# No process is on the other end of the pipe - Named Pipes in JAVA

Tags: java, named-pipes

I am using this codes in communicating with Evolis KC200 printer:

```
@Test
public void studyPipe() {
    try {
        String echoText = " {\"id\":\"1\",\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"CMD.GetStatus\",\"params\":{\"device\":\"Evolis KC200\"}}";

        System.out.println("CMD.GetStatus Request: " + echoText);

        String pipeName = "\\\\.\\pipe\\EspfServer00";
        RandomAccessFile pipe = new RandomAccessFile(pipeName, "rw");

        System.out.println("Writing in pipe: " + echoText + " in pipe "
                + pipeName);
        pipe.write(echoText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        // Thread.sleep(1000);
        String echoResponse = pipe.readLine();
        System.out.println("Response: " + echoResponse);
        pipe.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But all I'm getting is this:

```
java.io.IOException: No process is on the other end of the pipe
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:330)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readLine(RandomAccessFile.java:939)
    at
```

They have a test tool built on another language (C#) and their Named Pipe client looks like this:
What is missing in my JAVA codes?

```
 public static string SendRequestPipe(string ip, string port, string request)
        {
            NamedPipeClientStream objPipeClient;

            string answer = string.Empty;

            objPipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(ip, port, PipeDirection.InOut);
            try
            {
                // Connexion au named pipe ou attente de la disponibilité du named pipe
                objPipeClient.Connect(1000);     

                // Paramétrage de la connexion
                objPipeClient.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;               

                if (objPipeClient.IsConnected == true)
                {
                    // Send request
                    byte[] datain = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);
                    objPipeClient.Write(datain, 0, datain.Length);

                    // Get answer
                    int recv = 0;
                    byte[] data = new byte[1024];

                    do
                    {
                        recv = objPipeClient.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        answer += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, recv);                        
                    } while (!objPipeClient.IsMessageComplete);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                      

            }
            finally
            {
                objPipeClient.Close();
                objPipeClient.Dispose();
            }

            return answer;
        }
```

I also tried similar approaches in Java but I'm getting the same error.

UPDATE:

I think I know the issue already but I still do not have the resolution.
It seems that the JAVA code is creating another instance of the PIPE that is why it is not receiving any process on that new instance.
I tested with the C# code and it was not creating a new instance.

I checked the instances using this tool:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pipelist

Comment: It looks like the "other language" is C# and if my C# isn't completely rusty then it looks like they swallow any exceptions. Have you verified that the sample code actually woks? In that it actually returns a non-empty string?

Comment: Yes, the sample code works. That is why it is frustrating why I cannot do it in JAVA

Comment: Are you sure of your pipe's path? Looks like you successfully create a pipe and write to it but then fail to read from it because nothing else wrote anything in it.